# Servicestack + model binding on json post using AngularJs

Tags: rest, angularjs, servicestack

I'm calling a REST service developed in serviceStack, I'm using angularJs as a client but my problem is that for some reason I can't bind my json model with my requestDTO.

my angularJs code:

I have a AngularJs Service

```
angular.module('mseApp.services', ['ngResource']).
    factory('loginService',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/Api/User/login', '',
                {
                    query: {
                        method: 'POST',
                        params:{  }
                    }
                });
        });
```

controller:

```
function loginCtrl($scope, loginService) {
   $scope.submit = function () {
       var user = loginService.query({loginRequest:$scope.loginRequest});
   };
}
```

View:

```
<div>
     <div ng-model="loginRequest">
         <form ng-submit="submit()"  ng-controller="loginCtrl">

             <input id="username" ng-model="loginRequest.Username"  type="text" name="text"  />
             <input id="password" ng-model="loginRequest.Password" type="text" name="text" />
             <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
             <span ng-model="Username"></span>


         </form>

     </div>
</div>
```

on the dot net side

my DTO

```
 public class LoginRequest
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }

 public UserResponse Post(LoginRequest loginRequest)
 {
 }
```

everything if fine the only problem is that LoginRequest is null on my service method.

Any ideas???

Comment: why are u sending query({loginRequest:$scope.loginRequest}) just send query($scope.loginRequest)

Comment: I thought that the json class had to match the dto definition, I changed as you said just to $scope.loginRequest and it's working now, the json just contains the plain parameters, thanks @Ajaybeniwal

Comment: posted as answer pls accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just send

```
query($scope.loginRequest)
```

instead of

```
query({loginRequest:$scope.loginRequest})
```

that will solve your issue.

Comment: Some explanation will improve the usefulness of answer if someone else is reading it other than user who has asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also utilize the $promise object of your query to defer processing of your binding to $scope

```
function loginCtrl($scope, loginService) {
  $scope.submit = function () {
  var user = loginService.query.$promise.then(function (promise) {
    $scope.userResponse = promise.d;
   });
 };
}
```

then bind to (assuming your Username is at UserResponse.Username) like this

```
<span ng-model="UserResponse.Username"></span>
```